# how get input of multiple lines

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

**I have written code to take input as list of string**

```
d=["","","","","","","","","",""]
i=0
while(True):
  s=input()
  d[i]=s
  i=i+1
  if s=="":
    break
```

But I am not able to process list `d` to obtain required output.
`d[0]` is storing `Djokovic:Murray:2-6,6-7,7-6,6-3,6-1`. Now I want to process this string (or convert it into a dictionary)

Now I am able to write code (by using `str.split(",")` function) to calculate;

- Number of best-of-5 set matches won
- Number of best-of-3 set matches won
- Number of sets won
- Number of games won
- Number of sets lost
- Number of games lost

Comment: What do you mean you can't process your list?  You mean you are unable to change the value of 'd' in your loop?

Comment: What do you mean? What exactly is preventing you from using list `d`?

Comment: It sounds like you expect the input to already be broken up into a list -- it isn't.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes. I think that he wants to specify a delimiter for adding things to his list.

Comment: Please clarify your question, so that we can solve an exact problem.

Comment: d[0] is storing "Djokovic:Murray:2-6,6-7,7-6,6-3,6-1" now i want to process this string(Either converting into dictionary) to calculate
    Number of best-of-5 set matches won
    Number of best-of-3 set matches won
    Number of sets won
    Number of games won
    Number of sets lost
    Number of games lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
>>> d=[]
>>> while(True):
...   s=raw_input()
...   if s=="":break
...   temp = [s]
...   d.append(temp)
... 
a,b,7-6,7-6,6-3
c,d,7-4,7-6,6-2
e,f,6-4,7-6,6-2

>>> d
[['a,b,7-6,7-6,6-3'], ['c,d,7-4,7-6,6-2'], ['e,f,6-4,7-6,6-2']]
```

This makes a list item out of the input and then appends that list to your main list `d`
You now should be able to process `d`

Edit:

If you persist in using 2 delimiters both `:` and `,` you are making life more difficult for yourself, Stick with one!
Revising the simple code above:

```
d=[]
while(True):
    s=raw_input()
    if s=="":break
    temp = [s]
    d.append(temp)              #d becomes a list of lists
for item in d:                  #process individual lists in d
    x=item[0].split(",")        # break up the list using the delimiter comma
    for i in range(0,len(x)):   #access each item in x
        print x[i]
```

Input:
Djokovic,Murray,2-6,6-7,7-6,6-3,6-1
Bloggs,Smith,2-6,6-7,7-6,6-3,6-3
Jones,Abernathy,6-3,6-3,6-3

Output:

```
Djokovic    
Murray
2-6
6-7
7-6
6-3
6-1
Bloggs
Smith
2-6
6-7
7-6
6-3
6-3
Jones
Abernathy
6-3
6-3
6-3
```

Comment: d[0] is storing "Djokovic:Murray:2-6,6-7,7-6,6-3,6-1" now i want to process this string(Either converting into dictionary) to calculate Number of best-of-5 set matches won Number of best-of-3 set matches won Number of sets won Number of games won Number of sets lost Number of games lost

Comment: thanks for your suggestion to use function **str.split(",")**, this solved my whole problem in code. Now i had stored result in dictionary as pStats={'Murray':[2,2,16,143,13,142],'Djokovic':[3,1,13,142,16,143],'Muguruza':[0,0,1,12,2,15],'Williams':[0,1,2,15,1,12]}. Now i want to **print output in decreasing order of ranking**, where the ranking is according to the criteria 1-6 in that order (compare item 1, if equal compare item 2, if equal compare item 3 etc, noting that for items 5 and 6 the comparison is reversed).

Comment: print out the following.....

Djokovic 3 1 13 142 16 143\n
Murray 2 2 16 143 13 142\n
Williams 0 1 2 15 1 12\n
Muguruza 0 0 1 12 2 15\n

Comment: Given that another answer is the accepted one, I fail to see why you are asking me. So far your question has been answered and you have now tacked 2 extra questions on to it, StackOverflow doesn't work like that. You should post a new question, if you have one, based on your current code, of which we know nothing. As @Mr.goosberry pointed out, this is not a coding service, you are going to have to do some research of your own.

Answer (score 0):

Since your stats seem to be separated by a whitespace delimiter, you can use `str.split()` to separate each of your stats into a list. here is a demo:

```
stats = "Djokovic:Murray:2-6,6-7,7-6,6-3,6-1 Murray:Djokovic:6-3,4-6,6-4,6-3"

def compile_stats(stats):
    stats_lst = list(stats.split(" ")) # using str.split to 
    # split the string every time whitespace is found.
    return stats_lst 


print(compile_stats(stats)) 
# output:['Djokovic:Murray:2-6,6-7,7-6,6-3,6-1', 'Murray:Djokovic:6-3,4-6,6-4,6-3']
```

It takes each stat, and makes it its own separate list item.

Comment: d[0] is storing "Djokovic:Murray:2-6,6-7,7-6,6-3,6-1" now i want to process this string(Either converting into dictionary) to calculate Number of best-of-5 set matches won Number of best-of-3 set matches won Number of sets won Number of games won Number of sets lost Number of games lost

Comment: @kunalsharma I'm afraid I cannot hep with that. Your **original** question has been answer, and from the looks of your comment, your **original** problem has been solved. If you want to ask another question, please create a new post. Stack Overflow **is not a coding service**. We can help, however, with **already written code**. Once you have made an attempt, feel free to come back and post a question.